# I have an old version of jQuery showing up. How do I figure out where it is coming from?

Tags: jquery, javascript

I am fairly new to WP, so I apologize for this very basic question, but I am working on a [site](http://opteracreative.com/~baybr/) that has an older version of jQuery showing up.

Here is the jQuery reference I have placed in the header, which appears on line 20 of the source code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But on line 39 of the source code I see the following:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js?ver=3.8.1'></script>
```

I have searched the files and I cannot see where this reference is coming from. I need to get rid of it and could therefore use some guidance on tracking it down. Thanks.

Comment: Is line 39 still located in the header? If 'Yes' check `header.php` for the file, Found it? 'No' -> check `functions.php` and look for an `enquque_script` function. Found it? 'No' -> try disabling all your plugins. These are the 3 things I would check.

Comment: Hi Howdy_McGee, it was in the functions.php file. Please promote your comment to an answer so I can give you credit. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        Is line 39 located in the `<header></header>`?
                        /       \
                      Yes       No
                      /           \
                  Remove it     Check `functions.php` 
                                look for `enqueue_script()`.
                                Found it?
                                /       \
                              Yes       No
                             /            \
                        Remove it       Disable All Plugins.
                                        Is it gone?
                                        /     \
                                      Yes     No
                                      /         \
                                  Remove it     Re-search all
                                                Template Files.
                                                Found it?
                                                /       \
                                              Yes       No
                                              /           \
                                          Remove it      You're SoL
```